# Return filename with zipgrep

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to find a certain string within a folder of zip files. Whatever I try, I can't get zipgrep to return the actual filename. (so, "file.zip")

It keeps returning the files within the zip

```
./ -type f -name "*.zip" -exec zipgrep -l -H "string" {} \;
```

Expected output; "file.zip"

Comment: The code you provided results in an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` removes the name of the file, in case there's only one file:

```
grep "something" file.txt => you'll just see "something"

grep "something" *.txt    => you'll see "file.txt : something"
```

So, the best way to see the filename, is to make believe that `grep` is looking at multiple files, like `/dev/null`.

Therefore, I'd propose you to replace:

```
zipgrep -l -H "string" {} \;
```

by:

```
zipgrep -l -H "string" {} /dev/null \;
```

There's obviously nothing in `/dev/null`, but you're telling `grep` to look into two files, so he'll add the filename.